# Looking for dataset with US and other addresses

Tags: nlp, pytorch, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm looking for dataset which contain address within some sentences to train NER, preferable US addresses. Can't find such dataset. Do you know any?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you don't find any, addresses are personal information and it's hard to publish these nowadays, at least in Europe. You can try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

How about the Australian Address Data: https://geoscape.com.au/data/g-naf/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't fit,  address should be within some meaning sentences, you can't train NER on pure addresses list.  I think this maybe some  documents in financial or legal domain.